# How can i take backup of Basket Note pads from command line?

Tags: backup

I am using [Basket note pads](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/basket.1.html). There is option to take backup in GUI, but can i take backup from command line or Can i schedule it from gui?

I want to enable backup of [Basket note pads](https://basket-notepads.github.io/) once in a day. Please suggest.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

The option  **-f** or **--data-folder**    allows you to define where the data is saved[.](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/basket/+question/690563)  Put the data where you have other things you back up daily.